# Minus signs on coordinates not visible enough with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, coordinates

I want to draw a system of coordinates with TikZ. At the moment I use the following code (which I copied from somewhere). Now I would like to make the minus signs on the negative y-coordinates more visible, e.g. by moving the label slightly below. How would I achieve that?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.7]
\draw[step=.5cm,help lines,dashed] (-2.4,-2.4) grid (2.4,2.4); 
\draw (0.1, 0) node[anchor=north] {$0$}; 
\draw[thick, ->] (-2.5,0) -- (2.5,0) node[below] {x}; \draw[thick, ->] (0,-2.5) -- (0,2.5) node [left] {y}; 
\foreach \x/\xtext in {-4,-3,-2,-1,1, 2,3,4}
   \draw (0.5 * \x cm,1pt) -- (0.5 * \x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\xtext$};
\foreach \y/\ytext in {-4,-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3,4}
   \draw (1pt,\y*0.5 cm) -- (-1pt,\y*0.5 cm) node[anchor=north]{$\ytext$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Minus signs look visible enough to me.

Comment: Sorry, wrong code. But somehow I think, they are too far away.

Comment: use `inner sep=1pt` or whatever you feel right

Comment: @JLDiaz inner sep=1pt only shifts the label on the diagonal axis for anchor=north east. I would like to shift it in other directions.

Comment: Then use `xshift` and `yshift` options, or just `shift={(-3mm,-2mm)}` or whatever

Comment: @JLDiaz Thank you, that is what I wanted. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if I don't fully understand the problem, you can apply `xshift` or `yshift` to a node to displace where is finally put (unless you are using named coordinates to specify the node coordinates, which is not your case). So, for example:

```
\foreach \y/\ytext in {-4,-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3,4}
   \draw (1pt,\y*0.5 cm) -- (-1pt,\y*0.5 cm) 
       node[xshift=-3mm, yshift=2mm, anchor=north]{$\ytext$};
```

This can be shortened if you use `shift` option:

```
\foreach \y/\ytext in {-4,-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3,4}
   \draw (1pt,\y*0.5 cm) -- (-1pt,\y*0.5 cm) 
       node[shift={(-3mm, 2mm)}, anchor=north]{$\ytext$};
```